# Scaling form controls according to screen resolution

Tags: vb.net, screen-resolution

I am trying to write program in vb 2010 that is independent of screen resolution.

I am designing the program in 1920*1080 and when I change the resolution to e.g. 800*600 everything blows up and the program won't fit the screen. How can I fix this?

I have tried three different approaches:

1. loop through all controls and scale their position and dimensions

   ```
   Friend Sub ResizeControl(ByRef ctl As Control)

       '---------------------------- GET SCALES -------------------------
       Dim DesignScreenWidth As Integer = 1920
       Dim DesignScreenHeight As Integer = 1080
       Dim CurrentScreenWidth As Integer = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width
       Dim CurrentScreenHeight As Integer = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height

       'Ratios
       Dim ratioX As Double = CurrentScreenWidth / DesignScreenWidth        ' e.g.  800/1920
       Dim ratioY As Double = CurrentScreenHeight / DesignScreenHeight

       With ctl
           Dim height As Integer = Math.Min(.Height, CurrentScreenHeight)
           Dim width As Integer = Math.Min(.Width, CurrentScreenWidth)
           'Position
           If (.GetType.GetProperty("Top").CanRead) Then .Top = CInt(.Top * ratioY)
           If (.GetType.GetProperty("Left").CanRead) Then .Left = CInt(.Left * ratioX)
           'Size
           If (.GetType.GetProperty("Width").CanRead) Then .Width = CInt(width * ratioX)
           If (.GetType.GetProperty("Height").CanRead) Then .Height = CInt(height * ratioY)

       End With

       '---------------------- RESIZE SUB CONTROLS -------------------------------
       For Each subCtl As Control In ctl.Controls
           ResizeControl(subCtl)
       Next subCtl
   End Sub
   ```
2. Anchor each control to the main Form and only resize the main form
3. tried to AutoScale Mode

   ```
   Dim factorX As Double = ratioX * 96.0F 
   Dim factorY As Double = ratioY * 96.0F 
   Dim newSize As SizeF = New SizeF(factorX, factorY)

   AutoScaleDimensions = newSize
   AutoScaleMode = AutoScaleMode.Dpi

   Scale(newSize)
   Font = New Font(Font.FontFamily, Font.Size * factorX)
   ```

None of these methods has worked for me. What am I doing wrong?
One thing I figured out was that my main form is larger than 800*600 pixels so when I run the designer in 800*600 resolution VS cut down the with to 812px so my calculations of with and thus scaling ratio becomes wrong. This error goes applies for all three methods.

Please advise on the best method and if I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Assign the form's Font property in the form's Load event, leave AutoScaleMode set to Font.  You can't get it perfect.  This kind of user interface is very unusual.

Comment: I agree with Hans. Think about mouse movement - if you have a giant button in 1080p you'll have to move your mouse much furhter across the screen. Also what is your target audience? Will 1080p be worth designing for? Perhaps you should have separate layouts - one for average users and one for HD users.

Comment: @ Hans: Thank you for this simple solution. It's not perfect, but it works. However, I had to change back all the controls where I had changed the fonts type/size. I also set the AutoSize to True and AutoSizeMode to GrowAndShrink for buttons. With these changes my first approach also scaled the program as it should but the scaling factor needs to be adjusted.

Comment: @MorganTiley: the audience will most of the time use monitors with 1920x1080 that replaces 1280x1024 screens, but they also have laptops with 1366x768 screens. I though the screen resolution problem was a basic problem which there would be a (nice?) general solution since the diversity in screen resolution will only increase in the future... Anyway thanks for the comment. I hope I don't have to but I might need to use a separate layout.

Answer (score 1):

As an expansion to my first comment, take a look at some best practices from the UX (user experience) world. There is a lot of science and and deliberation put into UIs that work.

There's a great SE site - ux.stackexchange.com that you may find can answer your questsions better than SO.
Here's some questions you may find helpful:
https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/3414/desktop-software-design-patterns (see MS & Apple have their own guidelines incl. things like button widths)

https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/11361/responsive-web-design-technique-in-desktop-application

Responsive web design seems to parallel what you're doing. The idea behind it is to have your website be able to handle any client device - which is becoming very important because of the mobile explosion. 
I suggest doing some studying in these areas to come up with a good solution.