# Adapt form dimension according to screen resolution

Tags: vb.net, forms

how can I adjust the size of my application based on the resolution of the screen that the user possesses?
So far I have tried with Anchor, but does not meet at all my clients.
There are some of them who start their application on 11-inch screens, there are the lower parts of the app that are not displayed.
I want something responsive, that at the time the application reads the screen resolution and suitable all controls with an acceptable size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set the form's Maximized and Topmost property to True. However, the controls inside the form will not be adjusted if the sizes are static.

So, to dynamically change the size of the form's controls, you have to dock/anchor them. I suggest you to use the panel control to place for you to be able to layout the controls the way you wanted.

If that seems plenty, you can place this in the form's load event:

```
 Me.Width = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width - 20
 Me.Height = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height - 20
```

If you don't want to use the Maximized Screen property, you may look at this: [Change Resolution Of Form Based On Screen Resolution ( without changing monitor resolution and using Maximized screen option )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643693/change-resolution-of-form-based-on-screen-resolution-without-changing-monitor)

Comment: I put the autosize property to true but when I resize the form controls do not seem to scale your actual size. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Visit the following: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8359388/scaling-form-controls-according-to-screen-resolution?rq=1

Comment: I already see this, honestly I have seen so many solutions that now I have no idea what to do.